# HTTP 401 Unauthorized System.Web.Services

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to access a Project Server 2007 web service.  I am working on a Windows 2003 server with IIS 6.0 installed.  When I try to connect to the webservice after adding a web reference to my VS2005 code I get HTTP 401 Unauthorized error.

I have tried the following things and yet am unable to connect.  Please let me know if you can shed more light on it.  Here are the symptoms.

1. I AM able to view / browse the services in the browser.
2. I tried setting Credentials to Network Credentials with UID / PWD and DefaultCredentials without luck.
3. I tried to check / uncheck anonymous access for the services directory in IIS ( Should I be doing it at an App Pool level ? )
4. I changed the Account used for anonymous access to Administrator and its respective password from Directory Security.
5. I have tried to update web.config file of my client app to set authentication to Windows and impersonate = true.

Do you know if there is anything else that I can do / try ?  Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;896861&x=14&y=17) might have something to do with your problem.